# Should POSIX `read()`'s `buf` be `signed` or `unsigned`? Does it even matter?

Tags: c, posix, unsigned, signed

POSIX read function is defined as `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`, taking its `buf` argument as `void*`.

Does it matter if the actual buffer passed in is an array of `char`s or `unsigned char`s? If so, which one should I use? I googled and read the man, but even the *type* of the buffer isn't mentioned, let alone its signedness.

Comment: So `read` doesn't care, but you might consider what you are going to do with the data later. For example, if it is text `char` might be good.

Comment: Reading as `unsigned char` has the C specification advantage of no padding and no trap values - unlike other types.

Comment: What does code do with the data after it is read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for having the declared type `void *` is that you can read pretty much any type. You can read a `char`. You can read an `unsigned char`. You can read an `int`, if what you wrote to the file earlier was also an `int`. You can read a `struct div_t`, if that is what was written to the file.

Pick whatever type was written to the file, or if you're reading arbitrary bytes, whichever type works best for your later processing.

Comment: So what do you do when read(div_t_value, sizeof(struct div_t)) returns 3?

Comment: @Joshua What ?!

Comment: @Joshua Assuming that's not the size of the structure, exactly the same thing as if you'd read it into a `char[sizeof(struct div_t)]` and wanted to `memcpy` if the read succeeded: you issue an error message about a corrupted input file. (Edit: if you meant that there were more bytes to read afterwards, but `read` didn't return them all on the first go, still the same thing as if you had read into `char[sizeof(struct div_t)]`: issue another `read`.)

Comment: @hvd: Short reads are not an error. You should resume with `read(fd, (char*)&divobj+3, sizeof(div_t)-3);` just like you always would do if using `read`. If someone don't like doing this, using stdio/`fread` might be more to their liking. Calling `read` with small sizes like this is almost always a performance bug anyway...

Comment: @R.. In my initial comment, I assumed EOF was the reason for the short read, but in my edited comment I did cover the point you're making already.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it matter if the actual buffer passed in is an array of `char`s or `unsigned char`s?

No.  Moreover, those are not your only choices.  The buffer to which the second argument points can have *any* object type.  It's reasonably common for it to point to either a `char` array or an `unsigned char` array, but not so uncommon for it to point to an array of some (other) integer type, or to an object of structure type, or to something else.

The primary objective is to interpret the data received according to the data type intended by the sender, and that requires that you either know in advance or be able to determine from the data what type is intended.  In other words, sender and receiver need to agree on some kind of communication protocol.

The simplest possible protocol is an undifferentiated stream of bytes; for that, an `unsigned char` array is the most appropriate choice.  Some other choices are better suited to other protocols.

Comment: The other choices don't work very well. You might read 3 bytes from a pipe in the first call and have to issue another read() call.

Comment: @Joshua, other choices work just fine.  You are right that one needs to account for the possibility of partial reads, but that's an orthogonal consideration.

Answer (score 0):

"read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf."

Read() will store **bytes** from your file descriptor (be a file, a socket or whatever).

The bytes will be stored at your pointer address, whatever its type. The way your program understand those bytes depends on how you declared it.

so for example, same byte 0xFF may be interpreted as 255 or -1 by your program upon buf declaration

Answer (score 0):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html:

> The `read()` function shall attempt to read nbyte bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`, into the buffer pointed to by `buf`.

It is up to you how to interpret the bytes. Whether your `buf` is an array of `char` or `unsigned char` does not make a difference to the workings of `read`. Only you decide how to interpret the data. If the data contained in the file are not `char`, you might end up misinterpreting its contents if you treat them as an array of `char`. That again depends on your platform.

It is not necessarily correct to interpret the data as an array of `unsigned char` either. The data in the file might be an array of `floats` or an array of `struct` containing mixed data types.

Bottom line - you need to read the data into the appropriate object type in memory. To do that, you have to know what is saved in the file.